# jQuery - choosing sum at random

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a "whack-a-mole" style game for primary school children where they have to click on the correct number in correspondence to the sum given.

At the moment the program is generating addition sums like this.

```
function createPlusSum(total) {
    console.log(total)
    var int1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * total);
    var int2 = total - int1;
    $('#target').html(int1 + ' + ' + int2 + ' = ?');
}
```

I have done this again for subtraction and it works, but I don't know where to go from here in regards to randomizing whether an addition or subtraction question is produced. Here is the function to produce a subtraction question.

```
function createTakeSum(total) {
    console.log(total)
    var int1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * total);
    var int2 = total + int1;
    $('#target').html(int2 + ' - ' + int1 + ' = ?');
}
```

I use this to create the addition sums

```
createPlusSum(total);
```

How would I say I want

```
createPlusSum(total);
```

or

```
createTakeSum(total);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createSum() {
            total = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    if(Math.random() > 0.5)
    {
        createTakeSum(total);
    } else {
        createPlusSum(total)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method and it works. For some reason though, every sum has the answer of 9. Any idea why? @geedubb

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/24/ I have tried it again and every answer is 6. Have a go @geedubb

Comment: I have edited the above answer to sort this. The reason is that your total was being set initially only once as the document loads. With the above you generate a new value each time you call createSum()

Answer (score 1):

I would use random numbers again:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

switch (rand) {
 case 0:
  createPlusSum(total);
  break;
 case 1:
  createTakeSum(total);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not suggesting that this is how you should do it, but I am merely providing an alternative answer for thoroughness. (Pardon me, if the code is wrong. I'm a bit rusty with JS.

```
{
    0: createPlusSum,
    1: createTakeSum
}[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)](total);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign functions to array fields and call them random.

```
var func = new Array();
func[0] = function createPlusSum(total) {....};
func[1] = function createTakeSum(total) {....};

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * func.length);
func[rand](total);
```

this should do the trick, plus you can add as many functions as you want, just append them to the "func"-array

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that creates a random "add" or "subtract" question within the given range, and posts the correct answer in the console.log:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var total = {low: 10, high: 30}; // range
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var total = Math.floor(Math.random() * (total.high - total.low) + total.low);
    var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    var int2 = total - int1;
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) { // add
      var question = int1 + ' + ' + int2 + ' = ?';
      var answer = total;
    }
    else { // subtract
      var question = total + ' - ' + int1 + ' = ?';
      var answer = int2;
    }
    $('#target').html(question);
    console.log('Correct answer: ' + answer);
  });
</script>
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBxx/)